# When using servicestacks's DynamoDbCacheClient, what is the suggested way of cleaning old sessions

Tags: servicestack, amazon-dynamodb

We have just switched from using the ServiceStack MemoryCacheClient to using the DynamoDbCacheClient to store authenticated user sessions, and the switch was very smooth.  ServiceStack is storing auth/session data in to dynamo DB as expetced, and the Expiry dates look correct.

However, it has highlighted an issue in that old sessions are not being removed, regardless of their ExpiryDate.

I assume this is expected behaviour, which leads me to ask what the suggested approach is to clearing down old sessions, as without a change the DynamoDB 'CacheEntry' table will just get larger and larger.

Is anyone else using this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user tries to retrieve their expired session [it's automatically removed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/DynamoDbCacheClient.cs#L55) but the `CacheEntry` table can grow if an expired session is never accessed.

In which case you can remove any expired entries by performing a SCAN FilterExpression to fetch the CacheEntry Ids of all expired items with:

```
var expiredIds = Dynamo.FromScan<CacheEntry>()
    .Filter(x => x.ExpiryDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
    .ExecColumn(x => x.Id);
```

Which you can then delete from DynamoDB with:

```
Dynamo.DeleteItems<CacheEntry>(expiredIds);
```

As this is would be a fairly common clean up operation to perform I've just added an explicit `ClearExpiredEntries()` API [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/commit/8e2e224b77115ec11161ef8502fccb5fef084704) which you can now call on Startup, e.g:

```
var dynamoCache = new DynamoDbCacheClient(db, initSchema:true);
dynamoCache.ClearExpiredEntries();
container.Register<ICacheClient>(dynamoCache);
```

Or if preferred you could have it run as a periodic cleanup task every day/week/etc.

The new `ClearExpiredEntries()` API is available from v4.0.57 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the super speedy reply as always, I will do an version update and go with your new method...It beats my current temporary flush() that runs once a week at 1am.  Cheers mythz

Comment: Not sure if this is still being monitored (or who else is using it) - but this *does* give an issue for us now load is increasing.  This is because the FromScan will scan the entire DB store (an expensive operation in AWS terms), and can lead to throttling from the AWS end, and therefore locking out the application.  If run daily (for example), it will trigger a read of every item written to dynamo that day - which is likely to be over the allocated read units.  The write will also likely be throttled if the whole table is being emptied.  Any advice would be appreciated!